# How should I record the degree of interest of a potential customer?

Tags: account

We're in an industry with a small number of potential customers -- let's say there are only 1000 companies that might buy our product.

For each of these companies, I'd like to record one particular piece of information: how interested they are in our product.

Ideally, I'd like to have a pull-down list for each account with options like:

- UNCONTACTED: not contacted
- LIKES: likes our products, thinking about carrying them
- WANTS: wants to carry our products
- DOESN'T WANT: doesn't want to carry our products
- CUSTOMER: currently carrying our products

Is there a way to do this in Salesforce?  Am I even going about this the right way?

Comment: Add a picklist and make those as options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly do that. In Salesforce we call it a picklist field.

Go to Setup > Account > Fields > New (In the Account Custom Fields & Relationships section)

After that you will choose picklist and hit the Next button. Fill the screen with relevant information and click Next

Check the various profiles, who you want to see that picklist field click next again. If you only have one page layout for the Account then add the field to the page layout.

Click Save and you are done.

**UPDATE**

Based on the recent comment you could modify standard picklist fields as opposed to what I've explained that will result in the creation of a custom picklist. One such standard picklist is what sfdcfox mentioned in the comment.

The other standard picklist is called Type and you could delete the standard values and add your own. You can find the picklist under the Fields section on the Account object. The other one can be found in the Fields section under Lead object called Rating.

If anything is unclear, I'm happy to explain more.

Comment: Salesforce has a pick list like this already: Lead Rating. Default values are Hot, Warm, and Cold, but one can easily update the list to include their own values.

Comment: I agree, there is also a pick list Type where you can edit the values. Will update my answer. Thank you!